# what should be the ipv4_address when deploying docker compose cluster on azure vm?

Tags: azure, docker

I have the following docker compose file that I want to deploy to a Azure Viurtual Machine. I am new to deployment and cloud. I am really confused as to what to right in place of ipv4_address? In the following connection if I try to connect from within the VM it connects as the ipv4_address is 192.168.98.10.

But, it fails to connect from outside the vm over the global ip that azure provides.

```
---
# Source: tendisplus/templates/tendisplus.yaml

version: '3'
services:
  tendisplus-master-0:
    image: tencentdbforkv/tendisplus:latest
    container_name: tendisplus-master-0
    ports:
      - "30000:51002"
    networks:
      tendisplus-net:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.98.10
    environment:
      - REDIS_PASSWORD=password
      - CLUSTER=yes
    volumes:
      - "/data/tmp/tendisplus/30000:/data1/tendis/51002"
    restart: on-failure:3
  tendisplus-slave-0:
    image: tencentdbforkv/tendisplus:latest
    container_name: tendisplus-slave-0
    ports:
      - "50000:51002"
    networks:
      tendisplus-net:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.98.20
    depends_on:
      - tendisplus-master-0
    environment:
      - REDIS_PASSWORD=password
      - CLUSTER=yes
    volumes:
      - "/data/tmp/tendisplus/50000:/data1/tendis/51002"
    restart: on-failure:3
networks:
  tendisplus-net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.98.0/24
```

I also tried adding my global ip in place of the 192.168.98.10 but it sends this error

```
ERROR: for tendisplus-master-2  Cannot start service tendisplus-master-2: Invalid address 13.92.1.119: It does not belong to any of this network's subnets

ERROR: for tendisplus-master-2  Cannot start service tendisplus-master-2: Invalid address 13.92.1.119: It does not belong to any of this network's subnets

ERROR: for tendisplus-master-0  Cannot start service tendisplus-master-0: Invalid address 13.92.1.119: It does not belong to any of this network's subnets

ERROR: for tendisplus-master-1  Cannot start service tendisplus-master-1: Invalid address 13.92.1.119: It does not belong to any of this network's subnet
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set it at all.  The container will be accessible via the VM's DNS name or IP address, and the first port number in `ports:`.

Docker maintains a private networking setup for containers.  *As an implementation detail*, each container has its own private IP address.  In typical operation Docker selects these automatically.  It is useful to know that different containers can internally listen on the same port (as in your case both container processes listen on the same port 51002) but it is not usually useful to look up, know, or directly specify those addresses.

That means you can probably delete all of the IP-related settings from the `docker-compose.yml` safely, including the `ipam:` block in the top-level network configuration and the per-container `ipv4_address:`.  At that point you're using entirely default settings; if you don't mind the network also being named `default` you can delete all of the `networks:` blocks entirely, since [Compose will create the `default` network for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) and attach containers to it automatically.

(The one exception is if the network Docker chooses conflicts with the host's normal network.  If the VM is on one of the 172.16.0.0/20 reserved networks, you might need to override the subnet for the `default` network, using the same syntax you show in the question.  You still don't need to specify a per-container address manually.  Needing this is unusual but it does happen.)